# Bootstrap Datepicker Validations Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to validate the datepicker input control to disable all past dates, i.e all dates from the current date only should be enabled.

I tried using the bootstrap-datepicker library and used the js code below for the validation but I'm still a

```js
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
            todayHighlight: true,
            format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
            startDate: new Date()
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="POST">
   <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I'm still able to select all past dates.

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
            todayHighlight: true,
            format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
            startDate: '0d';
        });
```

```
<form action="#" method="POST">

        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

```
     <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css') }}">
```

I want all past dates to be disabled.

Comment: So it's working here, but still not working in my app, I opened my console only to see this error `TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem after checking my console to see the error being displayed each I load the page.

Re-arranging my js libraries solved it.